# Python how to use an operator specified as a string in an equation

Tags: string, operators, python-3.4

I am new to python and am learning it through and intro to computation course at my university. Our homework was to create this calculator algorithm that had perameters of only accepting the numbers 1 through 99 and only accepting the operators +,-,*,/,//,%,**. I am currently stuck at the end trying to figure out how to properly use the operators I currently have specified as strings in an equation. I assume it is similar to changing an int string into an integer or float, but that is about as far as I have gotten. The code in its entirety is below and all bold lines are comments in the code refering to the steps in our assignment. Thank you for any answers and if you have any critiques have at it, but be nice about it this is only my 2nd assignment on the subject.

```html
#Welcome and Rules

print("Welcome to calculator.py")
print("Valid numbers are 1 through 99")
print("Valid operators are +, -, *, /, //, %, **")

#Take in first integer that is between 0 and 100.

firstInt = int ( input ("Enter the first number: "))
    
#Take in an operator to operate on the integers.

opStr = input ("Enter a valid operator: ")

#Take in second integer that is between 0 and 100.

secondInt = int ( input ("Enter the second number: "))
               
#Prints the first error encountered then does not continue execution
#Errors include: values not between 0 and 100, or the operator is not
#of the type: +, -, *, /, //, %, **.                 

if (firstInt <= 1 or firstInt >= 100):
    print ("Your first integer is invalid.")
                 
elif (opStr != "+" or opStr != "-" or opStr != "*" or opStr != "/" or \
    opStr != "//" or opStr != "%" or opStr != "**"):
    print ("You entered an invalid operator.")
                 
elif (secondInt <= 1 or secondInt >= 100):
    print ("Your second integer is invalid.")

#Calculates the answer

answer = (firstInt opStr secondInt)


#Print the answer to screen

else:
    print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to do if-else statements based on the operator.  For example:

```
if opStr = "+":
    answer = firstInt + secondInt
elif opStr = "-":
    answer = firstInt - secondInt
elif opStr = "*":
    answer = firstInt * secondInt
```

etc...

If you were further along, I would suggest employing some functions to reuse/simplify the code.